# How to prevent lodash mapKeys from reordering my array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm using lodash [`mapKeys`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#mapKeys) to take my array of objects and convert it to a mapped object using the `id` property. That's simple enough, but the problem is that it's sorting the new object by `id`.

For example if I had three objects in my array:

```
let myArray = [
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Number Three'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Number One'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Number Two'
    }
];
```

Then I map the keys by `id`:

```
_.mapKeys(myArray, 'id')
```

It returns the following:

```
{
    1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Number One'
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Number Two'
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Number Three'
    }
}
```

My server returns the array in a specific order, so I would like the objects to remain the same, so that when I loop over the object properties, they are in the correct order.

Is that possible with this method? If not, is there a possible alternative to achieve the results?

Comment: This is actually native javascript behavior.

`var o = {}; o[3] = 3; o[1] = 1;` yields o: `{1: 1, 3: 3}` Why is this causing a problem for you though? if you are iterating over the entire list then you don't need it in map format, and if you are accessing the objects by key ID then the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah, so this would not be possible to arrange an object's properties without sort?

Comment: The problem is related to sorting and ease of updating. We could use an array and map the array for display, but it's a large array, and it's much faster to update using `object[property] = value` as opposed to looping over an array to find the correct object and then updating it.

Comment: Numbered keys always appear in order in JavaScript objects. even plain JSON notation `{3:{}, 1: {}}` evaluates to `{1: {}, 3: {}}`

Comment: @TomNolan JS objects is not an ordered data structure.

Comment: You can't force the numbered keys to appear in any other order

Comment: Right, so I guess it just won't be possible with looping over an object. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: @WilliamB it's not "JSON notation" it's an "object literal".

Comment: @TomNolan I would recommend keeping a map object for accessing the objects quickly and an array for iterating in a fixed order.

Comment: @WilliamB At that point you have two different places to update when data changes, though

Comment: Not if the map and array reference the same objects.

Comment: @zerkms lucky for me that you understood my meaning :)

Comment: You should upvote, or accept, or explain what is missing from the answers. If you have found another solution, it's encouraged to post it here and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) because each item has a custom key (like objects), but the order of insertion will be the order of iteration (like arrays):

```js
const myArray = [
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Number Three'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Number One'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Number Two'
    }
];

const map = myArray.reduce((map, item) => map.set(item.id, item), new Map());

map.forEach((item) => console.log(item));
```

Comment: [Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility) may vary. Even IE11 doesn't have all the features of `Map` implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments, the best would be to keep the object references both in an array to keep the order and in a hash to ease updating.

[Backbone's collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) ([source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L749)) works like this. It keeps objects in an array (`models`), but automatically updates a hash (`_byId`) when adding and removing models (objects) or when a model's id changes.

Here's a simple implementation of the concept. You could make your own implementation or check for a collection lib.

```js
// a little setup
var array = [];
var hash = {};

var addObject = function addObject(obj) {
  hash[obj.id] = obj;
  array.push(obj);
}

// Create/insert the objects once
addObject({ id: 3, name: 'Number Three' });
addObject({ id: 1, name: 'Number One' });
addObject({ id: 2, name: 'Number Two' });

// Easy access by id
console.log("by id with hash", hash['1']);

// updating is persistent with the object in the array
hash['1'].name += " test";

// keeps the original ordering
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  console.log("iterating", i, array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, looping over an object doesn't guarantee order. If you want an ordered list, you need an array.

However, you could apply the iterator pattern. In this pattern, it's up to you to decide what “next” element is. So, you could have a set with the objects (in order to get them in constant time) and an array to store the order. To iterate, you'd use the iterator.

This code could be used as example.

Hope it helps.

```js
let myArray = [{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Number Three'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Number One'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Number Two'
}];

let myIterator = ((arr) => {
  let mySet = _.mapKeys(arr, 'id'),
    index = 0,
    myOrder = _.map(arr, _.property('id'));

  return {
    getObjById: (id) => mySet[id],
    next: () => mySet[myOrder[index++]],
    hasNext: () => index < myOrder.length
  };
})(myArray);

// Access elements by id in constant time.
console.log(myIterator.getObjById(1));

// Preserve the order that you got from your server.
while (myIterator.hasNext()) {
  console.log(myIterator.next());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```